# Contour Integral parametrization

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

$$\int_\gamma \frac1z \, dz$$

where $\gamma = \{z \in \mathbb C,  z= e^{i\theta} , \theta \in [-\pi/2, \pi/2]\}$.
I know how to calculate the counter integrals (Last process). However, in this question, I just could not start somewhere.

I could not parameterize it and clarify the boundaries for it. If you can help me I would be very appreciated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just using the definition:

$$\int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{z} dz=\int_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}^\frac{\pi}{2} f(\gamma(\theta))\gamma'(\theta)d\theta=\int_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{ie^{i\theta}}{e^{i\theta}} d\theta=\int_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}^\frac{\pi}{2}i d\theta=i\pi$$

Comment: Thank you.You are the best!

Comment: I am glad I can help :)